# Bluetooth headphones stuttering and media controls not working Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have a pair of R+ headphones that work beautifully with my android phone.

However. When I pair them with my laptop using an Avantree bluetooth dongle, with generic Windows drivers as per manufacturer recommendation, I get stuttering and bad quality sound. Also, the media controls (back/forward) don't work except for pause. (I also have onboard Bluetooth on the wireless card which I disable). This is true for another CSR dongle as well.

I have scoured the internet from end to end. I've tried reinstalling/uninstalling/turning off bluetooth, sound and wireless drivers. I've turned handfree telephony/audio enhancements on and off in every possible way known to humanity.

I don't know how to fix this. Any suggestions would be very welcome - I've spent hours on it and it's been driving me insane.

**Update**

See answer below, but this problem still remains:

Now media controls. The default Windows 10 drivers don't work, either with the dongles or onboard bluetooth. Only by using an old driver for one of the dongles (there is no Windows 10 driver for the other), can I get the media controls to work. I would prefer not to have to use a bulky, outdated software/driver package if Windows can be made to work.

Any solution to the second issue would be appreciated.

Comment: You can answer your own question if you've already solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer:

It appears that the problem was a USB hub I have on my laptop. Apparently, some USB 3.0 devices can cause interference. Plugging it in would result in stuttering some of the time, but not when unplugged. Moving the dongle to the other side of the laptop, away from the USB hub, appears to have fixed the stuttering.

[Edit: working without a hitch, using original drivers]